# Calculate variable String(010) with integer(1) where outcome is string(011)

Tags: java

The user can insert an random string that can only contains numbers.
But it must been possible to calculate it with an integer.

the problem is the user insert a string like 010 + integer(1) it would result in 11;

but i want to return a string 011

But the user can also enter numbers like 001, 0001, etc

What is the best approach here? I have try to use

```
String.format("%05d", yournumber); but i does not work with variable strings
```

I also came across

```
String str = "abcd1234";
String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(part[0]);
System.out.println(part[1]);
```

If i use it like this i got a new problem.
how to split the number in a right way.

Any idea what i'm missing

Comment: How about cutting leading zeros ?

Comment: Sounds logic but can you give an example as answer. I'm Still fairly new to programming.

Comment: how you are taking the input? are you using `nextLine()` o?

Comment: the user can insert the input into a textbox where i check if it only contains numbers.

Comment: is the string binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you are handling Integer number (not binary )
Try something like this:

```
String input ="001";//your user input
    /**
     * your check here if input is a  number
     */
    int len=input.length();
    int inputInteger=Integer.parseInt(input);
    inputInteger+=1;

    String output=String.format("%0"+len+"d", inputInteger); 
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: great to know it helped , happy coding @user3475722